# Criando pasta de arquivos ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, .net-core

Olá estou gerando uma pasta de arquivo via código, porem ela n aparece como se de fato estivesse dentro do projeto/solução, assim:

[image: Imagem 1]

Gostaria de criar (via código) a pasta de arquivo de modo que de fato ela esteja dentro do projeto/solução. Desse jeito:

[image: Imagem 2]

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Ambas as pastas estão criadas, porém a pasta `silde` você não adicionou ela no projeto, somente criou ela, enquanto a pasta `exemplo` está como pasta do projeto. Esta é a diferença de ambas. Se quiser colocar a pasta `slide` no projeto, ou você coloca ela no `csproj` ou clica sobre ela com o botão direito do mouse e escolhe a opção `Include in Project` ou algo parecido.

Comment: O OP está perguntando sobre como fazer o include via CÓDIGO @TiedtTech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para isso deve instanciar uma variável equivalente ao seu projeto, adicionar o item a ela identificando seu tipo e salva-la.

Segue um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
var proj = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(@"C:\projects\Proj\test\test.csproj");
        proj.AddItem("Folder", @"C:\projects\Proj\test\test2");
        proj.AddItem("Compile", @"C:\projects\Proj\test\test2\Class1.cs");
        proj.Save();
```